# Irregular image gallery Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started to use the bootstrap CSS framework. With experience in Html, Css, Jquery and some others, in my first projectw I have problems with irregular image gallery:

[Here's template.](http://alkoholeregionalne.pl/wizu1.jpg)

I put code as follow, but that's not the best - in different screen it breaks down:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-0 artw najprawy">
<h3>abc/h3> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 najprawy">
<img src="yellow.jpg" class="biel pull-right" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 najprawy ">
<img src="orange.jpg" class="biel pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 najprawy ">
<img src="orange.jpg" class="biel pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 najprawy">
<img src="orange.jpg" class="biel pull-right" />
</div>
</div><!-- col-6 -->

<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-0 artw  najprawy">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 najprawy">
<img src="yellow.jpg" class="biel pull-right" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 najprawy">
<img src="orange.jpg" class="biel pull-right" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 najprawy">
<img src="orange.jpg" class="biel pull-right" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 najprawy">
<img src="orange.jpg" class="biel pull-right" alt="" style="margin-right:0px;" />
</a> 
</div>
</div><!-- col-6 -->
</div><!-- row -->
```

My own classes are:

```css
.najprawy {padding-right:0px;margin-right:0px;}
div.artw img.biel {margin-bottom:20px}
img.biel {border:solid 1px #fff;}
```

I suppose it's very simple solution, but I can't get it.
The template http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/shop-homepage/
doesn't work for me, althoug I'm using the same images properties (witdht, height). The problem is how to set the red, orange and yellow images in vertically the same line in sm-md-lg width, because for now I can't set yellow right image in line with right side of red one and orange boxes in line with yellow and red - they are moving with different screen.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Or problem for that matter?

Comment: could you provide a general example using your code with a jsfiddle? Your code is out of context and has several syntax inconsistencies.

Comment: Unfortunately not using jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To set the red, yellow and orange images on the same line in sm, md and lg, you would want to have them in the same row class to start off with.

Secondly, you would want to put the col-(size)-(number) number based on the amount of images you want inlined. If you do col-xs-12 for example, on a mobile device that column will fill up the entire grid thus pushing the next item to the next line.

Ideally speaking, you wouldn't want to have all of those images inlined on a mobile device anyways.

For example:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
    //image code here
</div>
```

The code above repeated 6 times would have 6 columns containing images  on mobile, tablet, and desktop.

However, that is inefficient, since they will be the same throughout devices, you could just shorten that to this

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    //image code here
</div>
```

That would have the same effect as the first example.

EDIT:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            //image code
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            //image code
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            //image code
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NEW EDIT:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            //image code
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-lg-6>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                //image code
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                //image code
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                //image code
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                //image code
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                //image code
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                //image code
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                //image code
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                //image code
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now THAT should do the trick. Sorry for the bad examples previously, did it in a rush.

Comment: @Lansara, Surely I want to have different set in mobile (col-xs-12) and different in others, therefore I put [code] col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6 [/code]

Comment: You would want to put col-xs-12 ....rest of code..... otherwise the col-md-8 will be inherited in the xs view and it will turn it into col-xs-8 as well.

Comment: That's ok for my need, but maybe it's impossible to get such a gallery in bootstrap?

Comment: Nothing is impossible. Try and fail. Try again and fail. Try one more time and succeed - that is the way of life. But I digress. Please draw a simple diagram of what you are trying to achieve in Windows paint or whatever editing software you have access to, and upload a screenshot of it and give me a link and I'll see what we can do for you.

Comment: Going to edit my previous answer and show you how to achieve that.

Comment: Added the code. Try that and see how it suits you. My method of nesting isn't necessary, but thatss more or less the structure you're looking for (not the only way to do it).

Comment: EDIT: I forgot to add two big block columns, my apologies. Check again in a couple mins.

Comment: Thank for help, but this code doesn't work - orange divs are wider than yellow ones. I fogot to add red upper div has only red background and menu inside.

Comment: You could always add an extra class in needed divs to put some padding or changing width of a column/row. However, the last code I gave does work to achieve what you showed me a pic of, the smaller specifics however are a different matter.

Comment: But how to put padding adjusting to different screens? The first row is simple - only one image, but second row has 3 images, their borders and padding inside.

Comment: If you look at my code (disregarding the first row), you will see that there is a second row. Inside the second row is two columns. Inside each of the two columns is a two rows (figuratively speaking). The top row spans fully, the bottom row has 3 different elements. That is exactly what your picture showed. Now to the question at hand: How to deal with the borders, padding, etc.? My answer to that is add a class inside the columns that need that styling, and style as needed. It's really that simple, unless you are envisioning something more complex than you're describing.

Comment: Thank for support. If I gave img-responsive class to img, that works quite better, almost perfect.

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I was able to help.